# Trackback implementation: rel="trackback" vs RDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdf, trackback

I want my Rails App to parse external websites for a trackback URL but I'm not really sure if I should just look for a

```
<a href="url" rel="trackback">Text</a>
```

or follow the RDF specifications described by sixapart. Or both. Wordpress and Techcrunch both only offer a rel="trackback" link and they should know. On the other hand maybe some blog only provides RDF and I'm missing the link.

What do you think?

And is there any ready gem/plugin out there (it's really hard to google for trackback...)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I'm now first trying to find the RDF information. If I do not find anything, I look for the link tag. I was refering to the sixapart specifications. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you provide some links to the specifications you are wondering about... from sixapart?  that way we can better understand what the RDF version of this should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm checking for both now (first RDF, then link if not successfull). I was refering to the sixapart specifications. Thanks for your help!